# Fold expressions in MSVC 15.5 Preview 2

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

Latest preview version of Visual Studio claims to support fold expressions. However, the following code does not compile:

```
template<class T> struct L
{
    void g() { }
};

template<class... TT> struct B
{
    std::tuple<L<TT>...> ss;

    void f();

    //void f()
    //{
    //  (std::get<L<TT>>(ss).g(), ...);
    //}
};

template<class... TT> void B<TT...>::f()
{
    (std::get<L<TT>>(ss).g(), ...);
}

int main()
{
    B<int, double> b;
    b.f();
}
```

The errors are:

```
22 : <source>(22): error C3520: 'TT': parameter pack must be expanded in this context
21 : <source>(21): note: while compiling class template member function 'void B<int,double>::f(void)'
28 : <source>(28): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void B<int,double>::f(void)' being compiled
27 : <source>(27): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'B<int,double>' being compiled
22 : <source>(22): error C2228: left of '.g' must have class/struct/union
22 : <source>(22): error C2059: syntax error: '...'
```

However, if I move the definition of `f()` inside the struct, everything is fine. I don't have such a problem with GCC.

Is it a bug in the MSVC fold expressions implementation?

Comment: Yep, bug. Please submit a bug report.

Comment: @Barry Thanks. I'll do it.